# onbeforeunload event on iframe is not triggered in google chrome, works in IE, firefox

Tags: iframe, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

If you set an unbeforeunload event inside an iframe, this is not triggered when you for instance click through to a link in the iframe. It works in IE and Firefox (not Opera, but Opera does not support onbeforeunload in general AFAIK).

Just wondering, am I doing something wrong? Should this behaviour not be possible? Or is it a bug in Google Chrome/webkit? Any workarounds?

Code example:

test.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Main page content</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {alert('unloadevent in main window');};
    </script>
    <iframe id="tpa" src="..test2.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

test2.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      self.onbeforeunload = function() {alert('unloadevent in frame window');};
    </script>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to for instance google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. [See Ticket.](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19418)

Answer (score 2):

I found an ungentle method to fix it.
In my parentPage which holds the domain "a.b.com":

```html
<html>
<iframe id="OBU" name="OBU" src="c.d.com">
</iframe>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        window.frames["OBUI"].frames["SubOBUI"].location =
                "a.b.com/demo.jpg?t="+(new Date()).getTime();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

In my "c.d.com":

```html
<iframe id="SubOBUI" name="SubOBUI" src="a.b.com/demo.jpg"
        onload="someMethodThatShouldBeExecutedWhileUnload"></iframe>
<script>
    var someMethodThatShouldBeExecutedWhileUnload : function() {
            alert(1);
    }
</script>
```

Have a try!

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is an open issue in webkit (and not about to be fixed soon):

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19418

If anyone knows of workarounds, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative may be to handle the click event in your iframe links at the document level or to pre-process the iframe page and alter the links to execute your custom JS handler. Then suppress the propagation of click event based on your business rules.